# Dealing with NTFS external drive on macOS

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, mount, ntfs

I want to use an external NTFS drive on my Mac.

I used paragon but since I changed my computer I don't have a license anymore and I would love to find a different method for using NTFS.

I read about `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and I wrote `LABEL=Untitled none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse`
and saved but still nothing. If I open my drive (Untitled) info I see

```
ritar write and read
staff read only
everyone read only
```

Why isn't it working?
I tried to change the drive name or use `cp` to move files but I get `Read Only FS error`.

how can I fix it?

EDIT:
I did

```
sudo umount /Volumes/Untitled
sudo mkdir /Volumes/Mount
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/Mount
open /Volumes/Mount
```

And now in that folder, I can see all the files on the drive and I can write inside the folder, then it disappeared. And now if I try to access my Untitled drive from the sidebar, it doesn't show anything; even if I enter in the drive from the shell, when I do `ls` I get nothing

What did I do wrong? How do I fix it? The drive still shows the right space so files should be there.

Comment: macOS only provides a read only NTFS driver, you can fiddle as you have done so that it appears to allow writes but it is too buggy to work. So Paragon I think is the only safe solution

Comment: I seem to recall that the Paragon software is a commercial version of an open source driver. You will likely need to find that or do as @mmmmmm suggests and buy the NTFS driver from Paragon

Comment: the OP can e.g. install  [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) and then use [NTFS-3G](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) to get write permissions on NTFS drives. In relation to the fstab entry - please use: _LABEL = NameOfYourDisk none NTFS rw.auto.nobrowse_

Comment: Paragon will let you use the license on more than one computer, just not at the same time.

Comment: @slartibartfast macFuse is not Open Source now

Comment: @mmmmmm and that impacts on macFUSE offering a solution for the problem of the OP how? Besides the included license is quite permissive: “…. Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted…” - but that’s really not the subject here, is it?

Comment: but how an i see again my files now? the mount disappeared and the hard drive seems empty even if the space is correct

Comment: @rita1989 not exactly sure, what are you referring to? In the Finder menu select _Go> Go to Folder_ then type _/Volumes/NAME_ where ‘NAME’ is the name of your NTFS drive. A window of the root folder of that drive should open…

Comment: the drive open... but seems empty while in the information (right click get info) shows 955 gb occupied)